# Find and replace link image to random string

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
   var string="<div><ul><li><img src='http://example.com/img1.jpg' alt=''></li><li><img src='http://example.com/img2.jpg' alt=''></li><li><img src='http://example.com/img3.jpg' alt=''></li>   <li><img src='http://example.com/img4.jpg' alt=''></li><li><img src='http://example.com/img5.jpg' alt=''></li></ul></div>";
```

I want find and replace each link image with non duplicate random string.
Example:

```
var result= "<div><ul><li><img src='adssad' alt=''></li><li><img src='bsdafz' alt=''></li>  <li><img src='soweuosx' alt=''></li>    <li><img src='qlolzas' alt=''></li><li><img src='owueweuy' alt=''></li></ul></div>";
```

Please help me !

Comment: You may wanna look into regular expressions. You can define a search pattern and then use a callback function to replace the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Modify it as per your needs.

```js
var string = "<div><ul><li><img src='http://example.com/img1.jpg' alt=''></li><li><img src='http://example.com/img2.jpg' alt=''></li><li><img src='http://example.com/img3.jpg' alt=''></li>   <li><img src='http://example.com/img4.jpg' alt=''></li><li><img src='http://example.com/img5.jpg' alt=''></li></ul></div>";

var output = string.replace(/'http:\/\/.*?'/g, function () {
  return "'" + (Math.random() * 16 | 1).toString(16) + "'"; // Return your own random string
});

alert(output);
```